# Validating ownership of a mass assigned model using shallow routes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, nested-forms

I have a nested route for two models like so:

```
resources :books do
  resources :chapters, :shallow => true
end
```

and want to be able to have a nested form for the chapters of a book.

how do I check that each mass assigned chapters book belongs to user.

I was trying to add it to the controller like so

```
class ChaptersController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :check_ownership_of_chapters_book

  def check_ownership_of_chapters_book
    if Book.find(params[:book_id]).author != current_user
      flash[:error] = "You are not the author of the book you are adding the chapter to"
      redirect_to root_url
    end
  end

  ...
```

it produces this error

"Couldn't find Book without an ID"

as the id of the book is not passed in a param.

but i'm thinking maybe I should do that check in the model (to check that the book that the chapter is inserted into belongs to the current_user)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this with a construct like this (and I have a deeper nesting of ressources like Author -> book -> page, Author -> picture, ...):

```
class ChaptersController < SecurityController < ApplicationController
```

(just the logic)

where AppController hanldes the check-call and SecurityController handles  the "check-check" like this (I wan to polute AppicationController as little as possible

```
class  AppicationController
    #check-call
    before_filter do 
        raise SiteForbiddenException.new(foo) unless check_permissions 
    end
end


class SecurityController < ApplicationController

    def check_permissions
        false
    end

     #check-check
    def check_permission_from(id_val)
        id_val={ page_id: Pageelement.find(id_val[:pageelement_id]).page_id } if id_val[:pageelement_id]
        id_val={ book_id: Page.find(id_val[:page_id]).book_id } if id_val[:page_id]

        if id_val[:book_id]
            return true if  ... check author from book_id ok 
        end
        raise SiteForbiddenException.new(foo) unless check_permissions 
    end

 end
```

and

```
class PageController < SecurityController   
    def check_permissions
        return true if action_name=='public'
        check_permission_from(page_id: params[:page_id])
    end
end
```

So if I forget the `def check_permissions ...` in PageController, I get an Exception

And I can use `check_permission_from(page_id: @page_id)` (or so) from any other controller, if needed, (ex. move a page from one book to another)